# express.static only loading to index.html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to get the static files (images, js, css) which are all inside the public folder to be available to all my routes. I am able to ONLY load them to the index.html. The management.html files does not have access to the static files, I am getting 404 error on the Chrome console.

Folder Structure:

```
-app/  
---index.html
---management.html
---public/
------css/
------js/
------img/
```

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: __dirname })
});

app.get('/management', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('management.html', {root: __dirname })
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Please show how you reference the files in `management.html`

Comment: Use absolute paths (starting with a `/`), not relative, in your HTML code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your HTML files you are probably referring to the relative paths of the static files. For example: `<img src="img/example.png">`. This link will be based on your current location.

When your current location is http://example.com/ (index.html), then it will refer to http://example.com/img/example.png, where the file is probably located.

But when your location is http://example.com/management (management.html), it refers to http://example.com/management/img/example.png, which will return a 404.

Using the absolute path of this file will solve this problem. You can do this by putting a `/` in front of the relative path: `<img src="/img/example.png">`. Alternatively you could use a relative path in `management.html` like this: `<img src="../img/example.png">`.

Comment: How come the absolute path starts inside my public folder and not my app folder?

Comment: @TimurOzkul That's due to the `express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))`. This basically says that the `public` folder is the root of your static files.